# Cartesian to Spherical coordinate conversion specific case when Φ is zero and θ is indeterminant

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry, inverse-problems, spherical-trigonometry

Following is the conversion for spherical to cartesian coordinate
\begin{align}
x &= r \cos\theta \sin\varphi \\ 
y &= r \sin\theta \sin\varphi \\
z &= r \cos\varphi
\end{align}
and we are using the reverse computation to compute spherical coordinate from Cartesian coordinate which is defined as
\begin{align}
r &= \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \\
\theta &= \tan^{-1}(y/x) \\
\varphi &= \tan^{-1} \left( \sqrt{x^2+y^2}/z \right)
\end{align}

Problem arises when $y$ and $x$ is zero so $\theta$ can take any arbitrary value so during Matlab computations this results in NAN (not a number) which makes $\theta$ discontinuous. Is there any interpolation technique to remove this discontinuity and how to interpret $\theta$ in this case.

Comment: You mean $ \varphi =\pi/2 $

Comment: Use `atan2` not `atan`. Or just `cart2sph` in Matlab.

Comment: I mean when φ is either 0 or pi.

Comment: cart2sph gives pi/2 for theta so  I guess I should clip all the value to pi/2.Thanks for suggesting the Matlab function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ r^2 = x^2 + y^2 +z^2 $

When $ \varphi = \pi/2 , ( x=y=0, \rightarrow z = \pm r ) $ so the point under reference is either at north pole or at south pole. $\theta$ is indeterminate here. Let not value of $x,y$ go below say $10^{-8} $ or so to determine a $\theta$ value.

Comment: Can you please suggest a check on the condition when x and y is exact zero . I should replace all the zero value to 10^-8 .

Comment: If you want to avoid exact poles, keep $x,or , y$ below 10^ - 8